# Visual Studio Code C++ Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code and when I type my code in C++ only some of the text changes color for example:

[image]

I do not know why that would happen and I want to figure it out.  Thanks to anyone that helps.

Comment: This is because Visual Studio code is not a C++ compiler. Only a C++ compiler can fully understand a C++ program, and VSCode is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's quite normal for editors to use for example Clang to do syntax highlighting. I think VS Code does not do it by default, you have to install a separate extension. Anyway, here I don't see anything funny, which the basic highlighter failed to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

That is the automatic syntax highlight feature of visual studio code. It will recognize the language by the file name (extension) and display keywords and constants in different color for better readability.

Comment: Is there a way to make main, std::cout, and << different colors?

Comment: @AarontheBoii0123 You should research "configure visual studio code c++ syntax highlight" and similar searches. Then you should try to change the rules. Then if it seems difficult, ask a question based on this basic research and trying. That way there is a reasonable starting point for someone to answer it.